# OnClick not called while I get OnTouch event

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue on my app I am trying to solve it from 2 days now but I can't find anything about it.

Almost every single button in a fragment which is added dynamically at my Activity onCreate are not clickable for some users. Nobody in my team experiences the issue so, I reached a user with the bug and made some test with him and here are the results:

If he clicks just once the button doesn't work but if he spams it, the button sometimes trigger.
I have also placed some debugging in his version and this is what I found:

```
user_hud_main_button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> report += "down;"
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> report += "up;"
            }
            false
        }
        user_hud_main_button.setOnClickListener {
            report += "click;"
            toggleMainButton()
            Analytics.send(Event.Type.BtnAddMain)
        }
```

edit: the setOnTouchListener has been added only for debug purpose while working on the problem

while on my test phones I get:

> down;up;click;down;up;click;down;up;click;

the user get:

> down;up;down;up;down;up;down;up;

The up and down events are correctly sent but not the onclick. Why does this happen and why only for few users ?

Here is the layout of the activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.hulab.mapstr.newArch.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/activity_map_fragment_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    ...

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_map_hud_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Bottom drawer -->
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include layout="@layout/main_bottom_sheet"></include>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
...

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_map_hud_container, UserHUDFragment()).commit()
...

    }
```

UserHUDFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ...

        user_hud_main_button.setOnClickListener {
            toggleMainButton()
            Analytics.send(Event.Type.BtnAddMain)
        }
        ...
    }
```

UserHUD layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/user_hud">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_hud_current_map_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/user_hud_main_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:elevation="1dp"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:useCompatPadding="true"
                android:src="@drawable/add_fab_button" />

...

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: if the onTouchListener is useless you must remove it and the onclicklistener will be called every time. Ontouchlistener and onclick at the same time is impossible i think

Comment: I have added the onTouchListener only for debugging to see if the view got touched or if something else caught the touch instead of my button

Comment: you should post the code of your fragments and your activity because it's a litlle bit abstract explained like this

Comment: I added everything I can

Comment: what is your problem now ?

Comment: What boolean value do you return from onTouchListener?

Comment: @SebastienRieu the user_hud_main_button onclick in the UserHUDFragment is not called except sometimes if we spam the button. But each time we try to click on the button, its animation is executed. It happens only for few users.

Comment: @Zain the onTouchListener is not part of the original code, it is only here to debug but it returns false in the debug code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that I had a "infinite loop" from my activity asking for a permission when users declined it with "don't ask again" option, so every click event was broken

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to have both onTouch and onClick listener on one view. You can do everything with onTouchListener.

Comment: I put the onTouch only for debug purpose, the setOnTouchListener was not in the original source code